# isOpen for only first element in ng-repeat in angular ui-bootstrap accordion

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I would like to use isOpen attribute so the first element will open at load. but when I try it with the code below it won't do it in the expected way. it will do open the first one but when click on the second one it will close the first one but will open all others. does any have an idea how to get around this?

```
//html
<uib-accordion close-others="accordionCtrl.oneAtATime">
        <uib-accordion-group ng-repeat="suffle in accordionCtrl.aContent" heading="{{suffle.title}}" is-open="accordionCtrl.status.isOpen">
          {{suffle.content}}
          <br>
          <button ui-sref="lesson" class="btn btn-default accordionbutton">Continue</button>
        </uib-accordion-group>
      </uib-accordion>

//controller
angular
    .module('neuralquestApp')
    .controller('AccordionCtrl', AccordionCtrl);

  function AccordionCtrl() {
    var accordionCtrl = this;

    accordionCtrl.oneAtATime = true;

    accordionCtrl.aContent = [
      {
        title: 'Introduction',
        content: 'What is a neural network?'
      },
      {
        title: '1',
        content: 'content1'
      },
      {
        title: '2',
        content: 'content2'
      },
      {
        title: '3',
        content: 'content3'
      }
    ];

    accordionCtrl.status = {
      isOpen: true
    };

  }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can have a separate `is-open` attribute for each group:

```
<uib-accordion-group ng-repeat="suffle in accordionCtrl.aContent" heading="{{suffle.title}}" is-open="accordionCtrl.status.isOpen[$index]">
```

Initialize the array in JavaScript:

```
var i, openArr;

accordionCtrl.status = {
  isOpen: []
};

openArr = accordionCtrl.status.isOpen;
openArr[0] = true;
for (i = 1; i < accordionCtrl.aContent.length; i++) {
  openArr[i] = false;
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/masa671/w3m4brLp/

Comment: Thanks Masa. that helped.

Comment: it requires to know beforehand your content. if your content gets populated dynamically you have to code a bit more, but the whole idea helped my a lot! thanks

Answer (score 2):

Basically the same as masa has proposed, but with two little optimisations:

- `close-others` is `true` by default and
- you can use `ng-init` to initialise the value

Code:

```
<uib-accordion>
    <uib-accordion-group ng-repeat="suffle in accordionCtrl.aContent" heading="{{suffle.title}}" is-open="suffle.isOpen" ng-init="suffle.isOpen = $first">
        {{suffle.content}}
        <br>
        <button ui-sref="lesson" class="btn btn-default accordionbutton">Continue</button>
    </uib-accordion-group>
</uib-accordion>
```

I'm using `suffle.isOpen` here to store the state as the most convenient way, but any other indexed variable can be used instead.

Based on a solution mentioned [here](https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/issues/2171).